# Can't find my cookie when logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

On my web site (asp.net mvc), I use cookie to store search pattern.

when I switch from login or not I get a new cookie , because the one created in the other 'environment' is not found.

I'm testing on localhost so I don't know if the problem will persist when setting the domain.
How come Logged in or not matters for cookies that are set for the web site ?

thanks

Comment: It might be a stupid question but are you using different cookies for storing authentication information and search patterns?

Comment: Yes, i'm using different cookies
authentication cookie is named : .ASPXAUTH
my searchpattern cookie is named :CurrentSearchPattern
I have some other cookies : ASP.NET_SessionId, __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__, _csuid

they all have host : localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry was totally my fault

I was clearing the search pattern on login/logout